# Whats the name for columns which purpose is not to identify?

Tags: terminology

I have a `contacts` table.

Columns are:

```
id
user_id
provider_id
title
phone_number
phone_ext
```

I want to know if there's a word that refers to the columns that make up the *meat* of the table. ie. (title, phone_number, phone_ext)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe application exposed, or user exposed, or non-internal keys? I'm not aware of an official term, i'm just spit-balling ideas since this seems to be different than Data Classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those columns are generally referred to as **non-key attributes**, in my experience.

Googling for that phrase backs up the fact that it is commonly used, if you need a reference.

Comment: thanks, and yeah, the google confirms.  I'll give a little more time for other answers before i mark it